# Get all div from table to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Here I have a code with draggable divs and dropable table: http://jsbin.com/exetuk/1/edit

When I drag div to table there are copy of divs with class .draggable

How I can make a an array with divs from table but every element to have

```
var arrayOfDivs = [{topPosition, leftPosition, lat, lng},{topPosition, leftPosition, lat, lng}{topPosition, leftPosition, lat, lng}{topPosition, leftPosition, lat, lng} ... ]
```

Is this possible?

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is lefPosition and topPosition? Where should it be taken from?

The script may be something like the following:

```
var arrayOfDivs = [];

$("#table .draggable").each(function(index, item){
   var lat = $(item).attr("lat");
   var lng = $(item).attr("lng");
   var top = ??????;
   var left = ??????;
   arrayOfDivs.push({topPosition : top, leftPosition: left, lat : lat, lng : lng});
});
```

Comment: yes but only divs in table... not from all page

Comment: left and top from table

Comment: and how to example .. print 3 element in array?

Comment: how to call 3 element in array arrayOfDivs[3] ?

Comment: In the table .. I changed selector to #table .draggable.

Comment: ok, thanks very much, how to print all elements from array or just etc. 3.element ?

Comment: 3rd element - indexes start with 0, so arrayOfDivs[2]

Comment: to print elements - iterate through them like
$.each(arrayOfElements, function(index, item) { console.log(item.lat); });